# How do you set tab view to scroll?

Tags: android, scroll

I have managed to set up a tabbed view for my app (woo!)

and have the following xml for the UI

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/areaSpinner"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/one_row"
     />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/cragSpinner"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/one_row"
     />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/routeSpinner"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/one_row"
     />
     <DatePicker android:id="@+id/dateClimbed"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/styleSpinner"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/one_row"
     />
     <Spinner android:id="@+id/detailsSpinner"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/one_row"
     />
     <TextView android:id="@+id/climbNotes"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/three_row"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

yet am seemingly unable to scroll down to see the rest of the form (cuts off at one of the spinners, why is this? and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem!

What I did was insert a ScrollView into the first XML file just "inside" the TabHost tags, like so:

`<TabHost>`
`<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">`
`<LinearLayout>`

... the rest of your stuff

`</LinearLayout>`
`</ScrollView>`
`</TabHost>`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the contents of the tab in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)?

**Edit:** After I fixed your XML formatting I could see your 2nd XML file.  You need to wrap everything in that 2nd layout in a ScrollView.

**2nd Edit:** Try editing your 2nd XML file so that it follows this pattern:

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
     ... all your other stuff
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: no, how do i do that?
the xml above is exactly what I am using at present

Comment: See my 2nd Edit to my answer above.

Comment: didnt work, i now, instead of seeing loads of stuff, only get the first spinner, and if i invert it so
<linearLayout>
<scrollView>
...

it crashes

Comment: set android:layout_width="fill_parent"               android:layout_height="fill_parent" for both the scrollview and linearlayout.

Comment: You can't have multiple children in a <ScrollView>.  Try this: <LinearLayout><ScrollView><LinearLayout>.  You are setting android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" on all these right?