# TabWidget doesn't fill in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android

I want to show tabs width horizontal scrollbar. I tried to implement like this [How do you set tab view to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492840/how-do-you-set-tab-view-to-scroll)

But the tabs doesn't fill the width.

**How to fix it?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                </TabWidget>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/destinationProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</TabHost>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117641/how-to-use-a-tab-widget-in-android

Comment: ... My problem is related to ScrollView. :(

Answer (score 6):

Solved it! Use android:fillViewport="true" and remove LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                </TabWidget>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/destinationProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</TabHost>
```