# tabhost xml not functioning properly

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have tried implementing the tabHost, and I'm pretty sure that I have done it well, but it is showing the output like in this link:

[TabWidget doesn't fill in HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896409/tabwidget-doesnt-fill-in-horizontalscrollview)

I'm not sure where I have committed the mistake.

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabhos1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:fillViewport="true"
                          android:scrollbars="none">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Most Rated" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Shop" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hotel"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Other" />
                </LinearLayout>

           </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

I created a new project and implemented TabHost successfully, then copied the new xml into this, even then it is not working.

Comment: Your `tabhos1` LinearLayout has its width set to wrap_content.

Comment: that didn't help, @Luksprog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it accidentally, just removed this line from manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

and I'm good its is working fine now.